# Make a page background transparent in cascades

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, cascade, blackberry-cascades

I want to make page background fully transparent in blackberry 10 cascades.
How can i do this ??

I tried with following code but it is not working..

```
Page {
    Container {
        layout: DockLayout {}

        Label {
            text: qsTr("Hello World")
            textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
        }
        opacity : 0
        preferredWidth: 780.0
        preferredHeight: 1280.0
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a Page transparent. Your best bet is to put your content in a Dialog, and set its opacity to 0. This will give you a full screen overlay over the current page.

[http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*cascades*_dialog.html](http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__dialog.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
background: Color.Transparent
```

in your container.

Comment: Are you sure? Since it is transparent you would see what ever is behind it, probably the application global background color. Your bar descriptor file should have a check box for transparent main window. I haven't tried that but maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: No the above code is used for container. The question is asked for Page transparency. So only the possible way is to make it as a dialogue and set that dialogue's main container  as background: Color.Transparent